# Theme Class por defecto para transacciones

Tags: genexus

Al crear transacciones Genexus asigna por defecto determinadas clases a los objetos.
Por ejemplo

Class Title para los títulos
Class Attribute para los campos
Class Btn_Enter para el botón aceptar

y asi...

Ninguna de las clases que asigna Gx es la que tengo definida por defecto en el theme.

Hay manera de decirle que clases quiero que me utilice al crear transacciones?
Porque hoy por hoy tengo que ir control por control haciendo botón derecho "Use default"

Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Como estas Dario?

Si en GeneXus vas a "Preferences" y te abris el nodo "Patterns", podes cambiarle la clase default que usa el patter por cualquiera que vos quieras.
Espero que eso responda tu preguinta.

Saludos

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Eso que comentás aplica sobre el workwith, lo que quisiera es poder definir las clases de las transacciones y que genexus las tome al crear la trn.

Comment: Bien, correcto. Las TRN usan un theme default que podes modificar en la kb e incluso asignar uno nuevo propio. Una vez que lo haces para la primera, el resto toma ese mismo style, incluso las TRN nuevas. Siempre y cuando mantengas los nombres de las clases estandard.